# How to uninstall a program (MagicDraw) and clean hidden files

Tags: uninstall, cleanup

I installed MagicDraw 17.0 SE in /opt running the sh I downloaded from the official site.

I had to re-install it because of a java issue, so I deleted the opt/MagicDraw folder and I ran the sh again.

The problem is that I have a hidden .magicdraw folder which has not been updated after the new installation, and I need it to be updated, since I messed with the files that were inside it and it's completely useless now.

So, how can I uninstall MagicDraw properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't install it as a .deb through dpkg you sadly can't use

```
sudo apt-get purge magicdraw
```

You would have to find all the folders it installed and remove them manually.
The `.magicdraw` is most likely found in your /home/$username directory.

To find any other files or folders that could've been installed with the script I'd use

```
locate magicdraw
```

and then delete every file it shows on there.
I'd recommend running

```
sudo updatedb
```

before using locate to make sure the information is not outdated.

Comment: I found .magicdraw, but I'm wondering why when I reinstall MagicDraw it doesn't update the .magicdraw folder. How is it possible? (thank you for your answer)

Comment: it depends on the way the script is written. It seems to be common practice to leave config folders in your home directory untouched even when you use ` sudo apt-get remove `. I guess they do this so when you later install the program again you still have all your settings. for example firefox profiles etc.